# Initiate restore of directory hierarchy in Glacier to S3?

Tags: linux, amazon-s3, amazon-glacier

Using software that runs under Linux, **is there a way to initiate a restore from Glacier to S3 of an entire directory hierarchy?** The files are transferred to Glacier using a S3 bucket lifecycle rule.

Restoring single files from Glacier to S3 in this scenario using the web-based S3 management console is trivial: right-click on the file in question and pick "Initiate Restore", then fill in for how long you want it to be available in S3 and tell Amazon to initiate the restore. However, there doesn't seem to be any option to do so on a directory hierarchy in one operation.

With a reasonably small number of files, perhaps in a single or a few directories, this isn't a problem. In a worst-case disaster recovery scenario, I'm looking at possibly needing to restore 10,000 files or more from Glacier to S3 to download back to my system. I would *really* rather not do that manually one file at a time.

I could of course use the Amazon API documentation to cook up something myself, but it would be really nice if it is available already.

Answer (score 0):

You can check out some of the products from Cloudberry Labs, particularly the s3 Explorer and the cloudberry backup (http://www.cloudberrylab.com)

Comment: Can you add some details to this answer besides the link? It's discouraged to just post a link as an answer on stackexchange sites.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest S3 Sync. They recently added support to restore from Galcier

http://sprightlysoft.com/blog/?p=147

HTH

Answer (score 0):

S3 Browser can Initiate Restore from Glacier from a folder. It will automatically download a list of all affected files and apply the restore settings to them.

The Free and Portable versions work great, but are limited to 2 simultaneous tasks on Amazon. If you want to increase this (to initiate the restore faster), you need to buy the pro version.

Am initiating a restore on 10,000 files in hundreds of folders on the portable version right now - well done NetSDK Software!